# Keeping user session alive problem

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I had an idea to keep my users' sessions alive by sending a webservice call, setting a timeout for a set amount of time (like 15 mins or so) then recall that same method.

Problem is the webservice appears to fire off continuously. Not every 15 mins like I thought.

A link can be found here: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ColdToast/HSUyS/1/)

Code here:

```
(function($, window, document, undefined) {
    "use strict";

    var methods, 
        settings,
        timeout,
        type = 'sessionPing';

    methods = {
        init: function () { 
            settings = { time: 5000};

            methods.request.call(this);
        },

        request: function () { 
            console.log('just before clear' + timeout);
          clearTimeout(timeout);

            $.ajax({ type: 'POST',
                   url: '/echo/html/',
                   data: {
                    'html': 'Echo!'
                   },
                   success: function(data) {
                     timeout = setTimeout(methods.request(), settings.time);  
                       console.log('in success ' + timeout);
                   },
                   dataType: 'html'
                });  
        }
    };

    $.sessionPing = function(method) {
        // Method calling logic
        if (methods[method]) {
            return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
            return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
        } else {
            $.error('Method ' + method + ' does not exist on jQuery.timeSince');
        }
    };

}(jQuery, window, document));


$(function() {
    $.sessionPing();
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
timeout = setTimeout(methods.request(), settings.time);
```

Your parentheses there will automatically run `methods.request`, which in turn will run code that automatically runs `methods.request` on down the line; basically, the method will execute over and over again, binding increasingly more versions of itself to your interval.

```
timeout = setTimeout(methods.request, settings.time);
```

That's what you're looking for: just passing the function signature instead of passing a function that executes as a side-effect.

Comment: Been there and done that myself more times than I'd like to admit. :-)

Comment: I should add: using the method directly will save you an anonymous function in memory per interval. Not huge by itself, but if your code runs long enough, you could wind up having a bunch of anonymous functions floating around. (I'd think they'd be garbage collected and wouldn't make too much of an impact, but it's something to keep in mind and you don't really need them here.)

Comment: Thats like 2 hrs I wont get back :/

Comment: No I completely agree and I didnt want them there anyway

Answer (score 5):

Fix the timeout so it calls a function:

```
timeout = setTimeout(function(){methods.request()}, settings.time);
```

If you do not do this, then the function that you *had* placed in the timeout will be called immediately.

Comment: Look at my answer, this is a really ugly fix, or ajm's

Comment: @Endophage -- you answer does **not** allow for extra logs or events in the `setTimeout` function

Comment: As it shouldn't, if you need to do that, abstract it into a function which does that, then calls `methods.request`.  Don't make unreadable code by slapping anon functions everywhere

Comment: @Endophage -- why not use anon functions? I never heard of the evility of anon functions

Comment: Nothing wrong with them performance wise, plenty wrong with them when it comes to code maintenance.  I've lost count of the number of times I've seen them massively abused.

Answer (score 2):

Functions are first order objects in javascript.  Inside your ajax success function you are setting a timeout:

```
timeout = setTimeout(methods.request(), settings.time);
```

However, note you are executing methods.request, not passing the function as an object for the timeout to execute.  The correct code should be

```
timeout = setTimeout(methods.request, settings.time);
```

Note I've tested this on your fiddle and this updates fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting your timeout to 5000 milliseconds, which means it will fire every 5 seconds, instead of the 15 minutes that you are looking for.

That would be 900000 milliseconds.

Comment: Right, but in any case, its firing over and over not every 5000ms

Answer (score -2):

Use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout` - it will be easier to manage and does precisely what you need.

Comment: This can become compounded especially the way the code is built (based on ajax)